# How to host same project on 2 server, Local and cloud

Tags: database, server, web-hosting, host, localserver

how to host the same web application on 2 servers so if anyone gets fail it redirect to another one.
for example Host on (Hosting server from hosting provider) and another from the local home server.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want a backup server to get initiated in case the 1st server fails.
For this you would need to do the following steps :

1. Create Rsync of your project files (so that always the data is upto date on 2nd server)
2. Have the database Master-master made (for 2nd server to have updated database)
3. Script to check the uptime of primary server, (a simple ping command can work) and modify the A record of the website. (This can be achieved by DNS provider API, cloudflare does provide which I used)

Script can also use a checker, where if the 1st server comes back up, it modifies the DNS entry to server 1 (which is the primary server).